# Show subset of data in MVC3 view page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm returning quite a few rows on a view page. I'm wanting to show several tables, each being a subset of the full results. I have a foreach loop, and I'm wondering how I filter the results so "ResponseCode > 400" and "ExtFlag = 1"

```
@foreach (var res in Model.LinkCheckerResults)<br>
{
   <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => res.SourceURL)<br>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => res.TargetURL)
    </td>
    <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => res.Response)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `ResponseCode` and `ExtFlag` are members of whatever `LinkCheckerResults` returns, you can do this as you normally would in a `foreach` loop in C#.

With LINQ:

```
@foreach (var res in Model.LinkCheckerResults
                   .Where(lcr => lcr.ResponseCode > 400 && lcr.ExtFlag == 1))
{
   <tr>
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => res.SourceURL)<br>
    </td>
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => res.TargetURL)
    </td>
    <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => res.Response)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Or an `if` statement:

```
@foreach (var res in Model.LinkCheckerResults)<br>
{
   if (res.ResponseCode > 400 && res.ExtFlag == 1)
   {
   <tr>
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => res.SourceURL)<br>
    </td>
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => res.TargetURL)
    </td>
    <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => res.Response)
    </td>
  </tr>
  }
}
```

Or (the *true* MVC way) provide the collection pre-filtered as a `ViewData`/`ViewBag` property.

Comment: This seem like exactly what I want. Thanks! I think I need to spend some time and learn LINQ properly. I'm good at SQL, but get totally confizzled with LINQ syntax.

Answer (score 1):

you can either filter your model before is returned to the view or do :

```
@foreach (var res in Model.LinkCheckerResults.Where(x=>x.Response > 400 && x.ExtFlag = 1).ToList())<br>
{
   <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => res.SourceURL)<br>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => res.TargetURL)
    </td>
    <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => res.Response)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```